# Get data from API and iterate over in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new in Angular2 and trying to do a simple task but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
products;

constructor(private api: ApiService) {}  

ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
}

getProducts() {
    this.products = this.api.get('http:/api/products').map((res:Response) => res.json());
    console.log(this.products);
}
}
```

But when I try to iterate in html file like this.

```
<h1>Products</h1>
    <div layout="row">
<!-- List the products using the class "products" -->
    <div *ngFor="#product of products ; #i = index" class="products">{{ products.title }}</div>
    </div>
```

There is no output shown. What is strong with my code?

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to subscribe to the observable.

Please change `this.products = this.api.get('http:/api/products').map((res:Response) => res.json());`

to 
`this.subscription = this.api.get('http:/api/products').map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(data => this.products = data);`

Also, consider changing `#product of products ; #i = index` to `let product of products"` most examples, guides use `let`. If you don't use the `i` from `#i = index` later in the code please consider deleting it to keep the code more simple.

Edit: Also add a new property in the component `private subscription: Subscription` and import `Subscription` from `RxJS`. Later don't forget to unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy` or after `this.products = data;`.

Assuming that `private api: ApiService` calls internally the `http` Angular service.

Or change to the template `let product of products | async` and keep the typescript code as you have it originally without changes. `| async` will subscribe to the products observable and unsubscribe automatically. Also `{{ product.title }` is the correct syntax and **not** `products`.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Property 'subscription' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.`

Comment: please add the `subscription` as i mentioned in the answer under `products;` line

Comment: I cannot add subscription. I have to utilize whatever I have written.

Comment: @AliRasheed: You said you have to utilize what you have writtem. I am wondering how it is working if you have not imported "Response"... See my answer below

Comment: Hi @AliRasheed i edit my answer. I assume this is an exercise/test and you cannot edit much. Please do some more reading on the official angular documentation because there are examples for so simple things.

Comment: hi @AliRasheed please accept any answer it worked for you or give some feedback.

Comment: i would upvote any answer but there is something missing in all of them -> `{{ products.title }}` this is wrong and it should be `{{ product.title }}`. anyways :)

Comment: Sorry, last time I did accept but I think there was some network issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your observable.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
}

getProducts() {
    this.products = this.api.get('http:/api/products').map((res:Response) => res.json());
    console.log(this.products);
}
```

needs to be changed to:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts().subscribe(data => this.products = data);
}

getProducts() {
    return this.api.get('http:/api/products').map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
getProducts() {
    this.products = this.api.get('http:/api/products').map((res:Response) => res.json());
    console.log(this.products);
}
```

Change it to: (No need to add any more imports)

```
getProducts() {
        this.api.get('http:/api/products').toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                let data = response.json();
                this.products = data;
        console.log(this.products);
       })
        .catch(error => {
       })
 }
```